# C# FileStream.Read doesn't read last block

Tags: c#, filestream

I read binary file to hex by block.

It is diffrent when I use FileStream.Read and File.ReadAllBytes

1. FileSteram.Read

   ```
   int limit = 0;
   if (openFileDlg.FileName.Length > 0)
   {
       fileName = openFileDlg.FileName;
       FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
       fsLen = (int)fs.Length;
       int count = 0;
       limit = 100;
       byte[] read_buff = new byte[limit];
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       while ( (count = fs.Read(read_buff, 0, limit)) > 0)
       {
            foreach (byte b in read_buff)
            {
               sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16).PadLeft(2, '0'));
            }

       }
       rtxb_bin.AppendText(sb.ToString() + "\n");
   }
   ```
2. File.ReadAllBytes

   ```
   if (openFileDlg.FileName.Length > 0)
   {
           fileName = openFileDlg.FileName;
           byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
           StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

           foreach (byte b2 in fileBytes)
           {
               sb2.Append(Convert.ToString(b2, 16).PadLeft(2, '0'));
           }
           rtxb_allbin.AppendText(sb2.ToString());
    }
   ```

case 1, reasult is ...

```
    ........04c0020f00452a00421346108129844f2138448500208020250405250043188510812e0
```

and case 2 is

```
      .......04c0020f00452a00421346108129844f2138448500208020250405250043188510812e044f212cc48120c24125404f2069c2c0008bff35f8f401efbd17047
```

FileStream.Read doesn't read after '12e0'
'44f212cc48120c24125404f2069c2c0008bff35f8f401efbd17047' is missing

How can I read all bytes using FileStream.Read?

Why FileStream.Read doesn't read last block?

Comment: I don't think this is the issue but `foreach (byte b in read_buff)` does not work for the last block. You should read using this: `for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)`.

Comment: @Kown if you increase your `limit` to that level so whole stream can be read in one go, you still face the same kind of issue ?

Comment: Tip: `b.ToString("x2")` would also print two hex digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it *appears* to you that it does not read last block. Suppose you have file of length 102. First iteration of you loop reads first 100 bytes, all is fine. But what happens on second (last) one? You read two bytes into `read_buff`, which is of length 100. Now that buffer contains 2 bytes of last block and 98 bytes of previous (first) block, because `Read` doesn't clear the buffer. Then you proceed with:

```
 foreach (byte b in read_buff)
 {
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16).PadLeft(2, '0'));
 }
```

In result, `sb` has 100 bytes of first block, 2 bytes of last block, and then again 98 bytes of first block. If you don't look too closely, it might appear that it just skipped last block, while in reality it duplicated part of the previous one.

To fix, use `count` (indicating how much bytes were really read into the buffer) to work only with valid part of `read_buff`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(read_buff[i], 16).PadLeft(2, '0'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need update offset and count.

> Sintaxis

```
public override int Read(
    byte[] array,
    int offset,
    int count
)
```

> Example

```
public static byte[] ReadFile(string filePath)
{
  byte[] buffer;
  FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  try
  {
    int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length
    buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
    int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
    int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

    // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
    while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
      sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
  }
  finally
  {
    fileStream.Close();
  }
  return buffer;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.csharp-examples.net/filestream-read-file/)

Comment: You should use `using` instead of try-finally-Close. But more importantly if you make the buffer the same as the file size - which is a bad idea for very large files - why not just read everything in one go?

Comment: You should review official documentation [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

`// Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
                int n = fsSource.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);`

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void ReadAndProcessLargeFile(string theFilename, long whereToStartReading = 0)
    {
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(theFilename);
        long fileLength = info.Length;
        long timesToRead = (fileLength / megabyte);
        long ctr = 0;
        long timesRead = 0;

        FileStream fileStram = new FileStream(theFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (fileStram)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[megabyte];

            fileStram.Seek(whereToStartReading, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            int bytesRead = 0;
            
            //bytesRead = fileStram.Read(buffer, 0, megabyte);
            //ctr = ctr + 1;

            while ((bytesRead = fileStram.Read(buffer, 0, megabyte)) > 0)
            {
                ProcessChunk(buffer, bytesRead);
                buffer = new byte[megabyte]; // This solves last read prob
            }

        }
    }

    private static void ProcessChunk(byte[] buffer, int bytesRead)
    {
        // Do the processing here
        string utfString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Console.Write(utfString);
    }
```